# React native with haul not working, throwing some loader issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I have added haul to my react native project to analyze why my release build fails. but I got another problem instead. I have a webpack.haul.js with following config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
};
```

When i run react-native run-android i see the following error. Can someone help me please.

```
ERROR  Failed to compile.

./node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/src/StyleProvider.js 10:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| export default class StyleProvider extends React.Component {
>   static propTypes = {
|     children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
|     style: PropTypes.object,
@ ./node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/index.js 3:0-48 7:0-15:2
@ ./node_modules/native-base/dist/src/index.js
@ ./screens/Academics/HomeWorkScreen.js
@ ./App.js
@ ./index.js
@ multi ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Object.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/console.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/error-guard.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Number.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Array.prototype.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Array.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Object.es7.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/babelHelpers.js ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js ./node_modules/haul/src/utils/polyfillEnvironment.js ./index.js

./node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/src/connectStyle.js 116:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (116:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|     class StyledComponent extends React.Component {
>       static contextTypes = {
|         theme: ThemeShape,
|         // The style inherited from the parent
@ ./node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/index.js 1:0-46 7:0-15:2
@ ./node_modules/native-base/dist/src/index.js
@ ./screens/Academics/HomeWorkScreen.js
@ ./App.js
@ ./index.js
@ multi ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Object.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/console.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/error-guard.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Number.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Array.prototype.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Array.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Object.es7.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/babelHelpers.js ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js ./node_modules/haul/src/utils/polyfillEnvironment.js ./index.js

./node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js 13:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   AppState,
| } from 'react-native'
> import type {
|   RNFetchBlobNative,
|   RNFetchBlobConfig,
@ ./screens/Academics/HomeWorkScreen.js 1:603-627
@ ./App.js
@ ./index.js
@ multi ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Object.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/console.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/error-guard.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Number.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Array.prototype.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Array.es6.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/Object.es7.js ./node_modules/haul/src/vendor/polyfills/babelHelpers.js ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js ./node_modules/haul/src/utils/polyfillEnvironment.js ./index.js


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDemshReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Hi, i faced same issue for ./node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js 13:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   AppState,
| } from 'react-native'
> import type {
|   RNFetchBlobNative,
|   RNFetchBlobConfig,

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that somehow or other, babel is not configured correctly to compile the features that exist in the code mentioned in those errors.

The specific problems:

1. static method properties (you need https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)
2. flow types (you need https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types)

It's hard to say exactly what is wrong with your config, but a faster way to test is to run the babel CLI directly on those files. If you ensure that `BABEL_ENV` and any other babel cli/env/API flags are set the same way as they are in the webpack build (you might have to do some debugging to find where `babel-loader` is applied), you can do for example `yarn run babel node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/src/StyleProvider.js`

If you can reproduce the problem like this, you can experiment in a much tigher loop with your babel configuration until you find a solution.

A good starting points is updating babel and all the presets/plugins you have installed.